# How to PROVE there are only finite number of sub limit in this sequence that not converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

for example, let $A,B,C\:\in \mathbb{R}\:$ be some constants, and
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
A, & n=3k-2,\ k\in \mathbb{N} \\
B, & n=3k-1,\ k\in \mathbb{N} \\
C, & n=3k,\ k\in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$

I want to prove there are no other sub-limits beside $A,B,C.$
I can't just say "its clear because all the indices are covered", I want some more "formal" proof. I thought about assume in negative that there is another limit $D$ and get a contradiction but I really stuck about how to continue from here.

TNX!

Comment: For your example, assume $D\neq A,B,C$ is another limit point. Let $\varepsilon = \min(|D-A|,|D-B|,|D-C|)/2$, show that $a_n$ is never $\varepsilon$-close to $D$, so it can't be a limit point.

Comment: @Christoph by the limit definition i get : $\forall \epsilon \:>0\:,\:\exists N,\:\forall n_k>N>k,\:\left|a_{n_k}\:-D\:\right|\:<\:\epsilon $ , and suppose for $\epsilon \:=\:\frac{\left|D-A\right|}{2}$, i cant see how can i get a contradict..

Comment: $a_{n_k}$ is in $\{A,B,C\}$, so $|a_{n_k}-D| \ge \min(|A-D|,|B-D|,|C-D|) = 2\varepsilon > \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

The general statement implied by the title of the question is false. There are real valued sequences with infinitely many limit points. For example, the sequence
$$ 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots $$
has all natural numbers as limit points. Even worse, take a bijection $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$. Now $a_n=f(n)$ has every real number as a limit point.

Comment: correct i'll edit

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose there is some other limit $D$ so that $D \notin \{A,B,C\}$.
>   Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}\min\{|D-A|,|D-B|,|D-C|\}$.
>   Note that for this value of $\varepsilon$ there are no values of $a_n$ in the $\varepsilon$ ball of $D$,
>   implying that $D$ is not a limit.

This is the basic idea of the proof. The wording could be changed a bit to match the wording of the definition of *convergence* you are working with.